# Select highest value and increment it one SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to update all the positions where the value is equal to 0, so I'm trying to get the highest value, increment it and set that value to the correct records as follows

```
UPDATE ps_category SET POSITION = ((SELECT POSITION, FROM ps_category ORDER BY POSITION DESC LIMIT 1 ) + 1) WHERE POSITION = 0
```

For example if I have 3 records with setted with 0 and the highest value in the table is 10 I want to update that records with the following values: 11,12 and 13.

The first part I wanted to achieve was to select all the records with `POSITION= 0`

```
SELECT * FROM ps_category WHERE POSITION = 0
```

On the other hand I wanted to select the highest value

```
SELECT POSITION, FROM ps_category ORDER BY POSITION DESC LIMIT 1
```

After building these two queries I made them a subquery that updates the desired records but this one is getting my in trouble, I can't increment the highest value in one.

Any ideas how to do it or usefull documentation? Thanks all.

---

Information related with tables

```
 CREATE TABLE `ps_category` (
    `id_category` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_parent` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `id_shop_default` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `level_depth` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `nleft` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `nright` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `active` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `position` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `is_root_category` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_category`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `category_parent` (`id_parent`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `nleftrightactive` (`nleft`, `nright`, `active`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `level_depth` (`level_depth`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `nright` (`nright`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `activenleft` (`active`, `nleft`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `activenright` (`active`, `nright`) USING BTREE)
```

[Table structure with sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwbQ5.png)

---

Usefull information

- Version: 5.7.31-log
- Engine: InnoDB;
- MySQLController: DbPDO

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a cte with the max number joined with all records where position = 0.

```
;
WITH MaxPosition AS
(
    SELECT MaxValue=MAX(NewValue) FROM @T
)
,RunningValuesPlusMax
(   
    SELECT 
        PS.id_category,
        NewValue = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PS.id_category) + MP.MaxValue
    FROM 
        ps_category PS
        INNER JOIN MaxPosition MP ON 1=1
    WHERE
        PS.POSITION = 0 
)
UPDATE PS
SET 
    PS.POSITION = RV.NewValue
FROM
    ps_category PS
    INNER JOIN RunningValuesPlusMax RV ON RV.id_category = PS.id_category
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't execute your query, it contains invalid syntax.

Comment: According to me, if maximum value in a table is 10, it will update all the current 0 value of position with 11 but we want it to be incremented by 1 on each update of row

Comment: Exactly @PRAKHARGUPTA and I think this is the hardest part of that problem. In theory when a query that contains a subquery runs, the subquery runs for each row in the main query.

Comment: @NauzetMartín - I did not see that you added the need for a running total after I answered. I updated the answer to reflect a running total based on max position and the sequence of id_category where position=0